# Probability 2 player card game with multiple patterns to win, who has the advantage?

Tags: probability, game-theory, card-games

$2$ people (C and D) decide to play a computer assisted game.  The computer is programmed to quickly play as many fair hands (using the equivalent of a fair $52$ card deck), until someone wins the hand so the win will appear instantly when they press a button on the keyboard and then it waits for the next keypress for the next game. The computer is necessary because of how infrequent wins are, thus a real deck of cards would take way too long between wins.

The rules are player C can win if he gets $3$ "gapped" $3$ card straights dealt in order.  An A (ace) will be considered the highest rank for both C and D so $A23~567~9TJ$ (T = ten rank) would NOT be a win for C but $234~QKA~789$ would be. There has to be at least a gap of $1$ rank between the $3$ card straights but can be wider as shown in the 2nd example. Note that the individual straights of length $3$ have to be dealt in order but the actual $3$ length $3$ straights don't need to be in relative order (as shown by $234QKA789$).  That is still a win for C and need not be $234789QKA$ (although that would also be a win for C).  The simplest example of a win for C would be something like $234678TJQ$.  This is also the lowest ranked win for C.  The highest rank win for C would be $45689TQKA$.  Remember permutations are allowed such as $89TQKA456$ is also a win but $243678TJQ$ is not.  If you think of each gapped $3$ card straight as a letter.  Such as with $234678TJQ$, X=$234$, Y=$678$, Z=$TJQ$, then valid permutations are XYZ, XZY, YXZ, YZX, ZXY, and ZYX.

For player D to win, $2$ pattern classes are allowed.  Either any $6$ card straight (such as $345678$) or this pattern: $223344$, $334455$, $556677$... $QQKKAA$.

The computer will keep dealing community (shared) cards until either there is a winner of the hand (not likely) or all $52$ cards are depleted (very likely). The cards are reshuffled after each win and after each nonwin (all $52$ cards are depleted).  Permutations are NOT allowed.  The straights and patterns MUST be dealt in order.  For example, $345678$ is a win for D but $357468$ is not, even though they could be the same exact cards.  Suits are irrelevant for the straights and other winning patterns.  Any suits are allowed.

So it is a rainy day and they play many hundreds of winning hands to see who gets more wins.  The question is who has the mathematical advantage and by how much? A hand that ties can be ignored as they will not count that hand and will continue play.  Neither player has any knowledge of the expected probability and both just play on a "hunch" based on the observed patterns to win which they are told about.

The $300$ bounty ends Monday night (Aug 22nd) around 11:59PM (Eastern time) already including the $24$ hour grace period.  Other simulations are encouraged but also math solutions or partial math solutions (like how to set it up properly).

Sample data of $3$ million random shuffles can be downloaded here for test purposes and/or analysis for mathematical solutions.:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BweDAVsuCEM1amhsNmFITnEwd2s/view

Format is $52$ bytes of data per line and $2$ more bytes for the end of line so $54$ bytes total per line, $3$ million lines.  "$2$" = rank $2$, "$3$" = rank $3$... "T" = rank $10$....   All cards are represented by this set of ranks: "$23456789TJQKA$".  There are $4$ of each rank in each shuffle (suits are irrelevant in this card game).

Where are the mathematical attempts at solving the probabilities of this card game?  How about even some partial solutions like take the winning D patterns and compute the probability of a D win if D was the only player, subtracting out the overcounting cases where $2$ (or more) of those patterns can appear in the same shuffled deck.  For example, if we get something like $234567223344$

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  What's a hand?  Nine for $C$, six for $D$?  Are they being dealt from the same deck or does each player have a private deck?  do the wins have to be dealt in order?  thus would $937JT65A2$ (a permutation of your first example) be a win for $C$?  If nobody wins the first round, is the deck reshuffled or do you play on with a depleted deck (in which case, when is it reshuffled?).

Comment: The computer will keep "dealing" cards until either there is a winner of the hand or all $52$ cards are exhausted.  If no winner for that hand then the computer will reshuffle and try again.  It will do this so quickly that as soon as they press a button the win will appear instantly.  Good question thanks for letting me clarify.  The cards are community shared cards.

Comment: As a general rule, games with complicated win/loss rules tend to be easier to analyze by simulation.  Program the game and let the machine play out a few million rounds.  In this case, it might not be that hard to count the winners for each.

Comment: there were several questions in my first comment, not just the one about shuffling.

Comment: Given that the players play on with a depleted deck, I reiterate my comment on sampling.  Counting winners would only work if you reshuffled.  Otherwise you have to recount the winners depending on the make up of the depleted deck...it seems perfectly possible to me that knowing there has been no winner for several rounds has a strong effect on the probability going forward.

Comment: In Blackjack, for example, the probabilities change dramatically if you play with a depleted deck.  In some cases, the advantage actually moves to the player (away from the House, that is).  That's why serious blackjack games either reshuffle each round or play with many decks (and still reshuffle more quickly than you might expect).

Comment: Well, I'm sticking with my recommendation:  simulate the situation.  Usually the hard part is programming the winning rules.  In your case, I still don't understand what a "hand" is.  Looks like $C$ gets nine and $D$ gets six, but it isn't stated explicitly.  In fact you give a seven card example for $D$ so I have no idea, really.  Programming the game will force you to clarify the rules.

Comment: Up to $52$ cards are dealt for each hand.  A hand is any number of community (shared) cards dealt until either there is a winner or all $52$ of the cards are exhausted.  For example, if there is a winner immediately after card $42$ is drawn, then that is a $42$ card hand.  I suspect in over $99.9$% of the hands there will be no winner and a reshuffle and redraw will happen.  This game is not amenable to real play with a deck so a computer assists to speed things up by several orders of magnitude, making winners instant.

Comment: You keep repeating the point that the computer helps, but if you have already programmed this then it ought to be easy to simply simulate a great many games.  I don't think anyone here will do this for you...A. this is not a programming site and B.  I really don't think you've explained the rules very well and whatever anyone else tried to program would almost certainly be wrong.  I will say one last thing:  given that $D$ only needs $6$ to win (and $C$ needs $9$) I'll predict that $D$ has a lasting advantage.  Of course, intuition is notoriously unreliable in these matters.

Comment: there are no general short cuts.  As I say, in this case...if you held a gun to my head I'd prefer to play as $D$.  It seems to me that as $C$ is building a winner,  it will look a lot like a winner for $D$.  If, say, $C$ has $234\;67$ then a $5$ wins for $D$ while $C$ still has a long way to go.  So, my guess is the game strongly favors $D$.  But, like I said, intuition is often wrong...that's why there are casinos.  I'd trust a simulation more than my intuition.

Comment: $234675$ is NOT a win for player D.  The rules clearly state all the winning patterns (such as straights) MUST be dealt in order.  These are unlike straights in poker where the cards can appear in any order.  Here, the $234567$ MUST be dealt in that order with no interfering cards.  For example, $234A567$ is also NOT a win for player D.

Comment: Like I say, the rules are not clear to me.  That's why I wouldn't try to simulate it myself.  if I were you, I wouldn't trust any one else's simulation for that reason...very high probability of a misinterpretation of the rules.

Comment: With a little back and forth clarification the rules are now clear.  This is why it is good to share ideas and inquire about special cases cuz even I missed  an anomalous case and I made up this puzzle/problem!   Just goes to show you that many times $2$ (or more) heads are better than $1$.

Comment: Is a -1 gap counted? (234, 456, JQK) I guess not. Brute force through all permutation is not possible (about 10^50 permutation) but you can save board state in 20 bits, partial winning data for C (like which 3 straight has been encoutered) in 11 bits, and optimize to 7 bit, previous some cards in less than 16 bits, then computer can solve the rest. Given those data, if there is an instant win, then we know the probability of that branch, otherwise, recursive down to other branchs (can use DP) and add the probability. ~10^15 CPU cycles is quite possible, but not memory.

Comment: The gap patterns are clearly shown , the first being $234,678,TJQ$.  D's chance of winning seems easy to approximate mathematically but difficult to get exact, especially when competing against C.  Actually the coding of this card game is not difficult once you understand some things to watch out for (1 pattern was pointed out to me that I didn't initially handle properly but has been since fixed).

Comment: this is extremely unclear

Comment: @mercio - What is unclear?  The gap patterns?  Simple.  $234, 456, 678$ is NOT a win for player C cuz each $3$ card straight  has "overlapping" ranks (the $4$s and $6$s for example).  $234,678, 456$ is also NOT a win for player C since even thought the $234$ and $678$ are gapped, the $456$ is not (it has a $4$ and a $6$ in common with the other  $3$ card straights).  The lowest ranked win for player C would therefore be $234,678,TJQ$ which is shown as pattern $1$.  Note each $3$ card straight must be in order (such as $234$ and not $432$) but permutations are allowed (such as $678,TJQ,234$).

Comment: If the sequence JQK234567 is dealt, who wins?

Comment: @Michael Seifert - $JQK234567$ is a win for player D cuz the $3$ length $3$ straights are not all gapped by at least one rank.  This is one reason why I require gapped straights for C to win cuz otherwise any straight of length $6$ (such as $234567$) would count as $2/3$rds of a candidate win for C, making it too easy for C to win.  This would likely take some wins away from D and force more ties.  It would also create many more patterns to check for a C win.  My restriction of C's straights being gapped alleviates these problems.

Comment: @David Can you give an example sequence that results in a tie? My understanding of the rules is that ties cannot occur.

Comment: @xidgel - Yes I actually included actual ties that occurred in my post.  They happened during the $1$ billion simulated hands.  There were only $22$ ties.  Ties only happen about once every $45$ million or so hands which is somewhat surprising.  A simple example of a tie that is  super rare but possible is the $12$ card tie such as $234678789TJQ$.   Here player C gets $234,678, and TJQ$ but at the same time ( on the final card Q), player D gets $789TJQ$.  The Q card ties both players cuz that is  the card both players needed for a candidate win.  Someone should compute the probability of this.

Comment: @lulu.  For a card game like this, one way around the problem of "not trusting" the results of others is to just post a sample data file and compare the results.  That is what we did.  It is VERY unlikely that a wrong program would produce a correct (matching) result.  Also, by posting the rules and letting many people view it, different clarifications are requested which make it clear for everyone.

Comment: @lulu, also, if the win probability was MUCH less than $1$ out of every $6000$ or so hands like it is here, then simulation might not help much.  For example, what if it was $1$ out of $6$ trillion hands?  I made this card game so it can be solved several ways, either using pure math, pure simulation, or a combination of both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the winning hands are so rare, I thought about generating them directly, separately for player C and D.

#### The chances of player D

For a fixed set of six adjacent positions, we already know the odds: the probability of seeing D's winning pattern 1 is
$$ P_{D_1}=8\prod_{i=0}^5\frac{4}{52-i},$$
for pattern 2 it is
$$ P_{D_2}=11\prod_{i=0}^2\frac{4\cdot 3}{(52-2i)(52-2i-1)}, $$
and the probability for any winning pattern for D at these positions is
$$ P_D=P_{D_1}+P_{D_2}. $$

To create a representative winning hand, we first select between winning patterns 1 and 2, respecting the ratio $P_{D_1}:P_{D_2}=512:297$. Next we choose between the 8 or 11 possible ways to assign cards according to the selected pattern at the positions considered, they all have the same probability. Then, we randomly distribute the remaining cards.

Since we don't want to only create winning hands which show a winning pattern at fixed positions, we also want to randomly select these positions. Up to now, nothing depended on that selection, so we can defer determining these positions to this moment. We shuffle the remaing cards together with a special marker that after shuffling is replaced by the cards forming the selected winning pattern. This way we create each pair of a winning hand and six adjacent positions that show a winning pattern in that hand with the same probability. If we forget about the selected winning positions, we are overcounting the winning hands that show $n>1$ winning patterns. To compensate, we could weight these hands with $1/n$. Alternatively, we can reject a winning hand that has a winning pattern before the selected one. This avoids having to use rationals or floating point numbers. I found that I can keep more than 95% of the generated winning hands, so I did that. Now we can generate representative candidate wins for D, next we can test if it is a win for C after all and also reject in this case (after counting it as an interesting outcome).

So what can we do with a stream of representative winning D hands? One thing is to determine the average number of cards needed until it is a win for D. I get 28.963 (after $10^{11}$ experiments, where an experiment consists of finding a winning hand that may then be rejected).

It is also possible to count how often a particular number of cards was needed and compare that to the numbers expected from a uniform distribution:

[image: distribution of number of cards needed for a D win]

But there is more! We can use the observed ratio of all D's wins to the wins after the first six cards as an experimentally justified multiplier for $P_D$ (which is the exact probability for D winning after six cards), replacing the rough estimated multiplier 47 that came from the assumption of a nearly uniform distribution. We get a multiplier of 44.66 and D's winning chances as 0.0158%.

#### The chances of player C

We can use essentially the same idea for player C. The probability of seeing a winning pattern at three triples of adjacent positions is already known to be
$$ P_C=3!\cdot 10\prod_{i=0}^8 \frac{4}{52-i} $$
(that calculation only needs that each pattern demands nine different particular cards at each of nine chosen positions).

We select one of the ten patterns and shuffle the remainig cards together with three special marks. Rejecting hands to avoid overcounting is slightly more difficult, because it is not enough to compare the last position needed to see that C is winning, because we might still use different straight first and second triples. However, we can just use whatever triples our algorithm finds as representative for one hand, and check if this agrees with the positions we used to create the winning hand. This time, we have to reject more hands, but we still can keep more than 85%. The following results are again after $10^{11}$ experiments.

The average number of cards needed to see a winning pattern is 41.10, the distribution is very different:

[image: distribution of number of cards needed for a C win]

It is a problem that the first value is so relatively close to zero, because it makes the computation of the multiplier less stable. (By comparing $P_D$ and $P_C$, we could have known that before.) After $10^5$ experiments (I didn't look at smaller values), the estimated multiplier for the player D case already had two good digits, while the estimate for the player C case was 50% off. That is no surprise, given that only four occurences of wins after 9 nine cards have been observed. After the $10^{11}$  experiments, 6581830 such wins were observed. The estimated multiplier is 13000 (with three plausible digits), giving a winning chance for C of 0.0153%.

#### More results

While we create 63.288% of the D wins as pattern 1 wins, only 61.565% percents of the surviving D win hands belong to pattern 1. The ratio of real ties to candidate ties (which can be determined from both simulations) is about 1:31.

Using the observed ratio of real ties and wins at the first possible position, we can again use $P_D$ resp. $P_C$ as "leverage", this time to get the expected frequency of real ties. The D winning data predict one real tie in 43974812 hands, the C winning data predict one in 43961799 hands. The result from the D wins is again more relyable, but seeing both estimates are so close is reassuring.

#### The program

The program to perform the experiments is written in C++11, compilable with `g++` from both Debian stable and oldstable with the option `-std=c++11`. It is too long to post it here, but if anyone is interested in it (or the detailed results) I will find a way to transfer it. Performing $10^{11}$ experiments took about 32 hours.

---

#### Getting better results faster

I found a better way to use my method of getting representative winning hands. If we multiply $P_D$ by 47, we get the sum of the probability of getting a deck that has a winning pattern in the first possible position, and the propability of getting one that has it in the second position, and so on. These events are not disjoint, we are overcounting the decks that satisfy the winning condition in more than one way: we count them twice if they have two winning patterns, three times if they have three etc.

We can estimate the factor by which we are overcounting by looking closely at the randomly created (candidate) winning decks. For all the created winning decks, we sum the number of ways in which it is winning, and divide that by the number of decks we have created. Dividing $47P_D$ by this factor gives D's single player winning chance. If we want to know his chance in the two player version, we have to correct by a factor that we can also estimate: the number of real wins divided by the number of candidate wins. (The candidate wins cancel.) This method is better because we don't depend on an estimate for the number of wins in the first possible position of which there are almost two orders of magnitude less than the number of experiments we have performed. We already get three significant digits after $10^5$ experiments. As single player winning probability we get 0.015787%, for the two player variant we get 0.015776%.

We can do the same for player C with an even better improvement in accuracy, but first we have to find the equivalent of the factor 47. It is the number of ways in wich we can find three disjoint triples of adjacent positions of the 52 cards in the deck. This number is 15180. (We could get this by stars and bars, but I already had a list of them for another experiment: If you take all these possibilities and count how often each position appears as last selected position, the result looks very much like the distribution of the number of cards needed for a C win shown above.) So $15180P_C$ is morally as good an estimate for C's chances as $47P_D$ is for D's, however it is less accurate, it is almost 17% off. Estimating the correction factor again gives three significant digits after only $10^5$ experiments. Eventually, we get 0.015332% as C's single player winning chance and 0.015271% for the two player variant.

(I missed a simpler way to estimate the overcounting factor. We just need to divide the number of experiments by the number of winning decks that we keep as representative. This avoids having to find the number of ways in which a deck is winning, which is slightly tricky for C. However, being able to do it will be useful in the next section.)

#### Strict bounds for the single player variants

(I'll add this part later. It's nice, but not enough to really prove that D's chances are better.)

Comment: Very nice.  Can you run your program on the 3 million deck  test data  to help confirm you are getting the same results?  I guess I had the right idea trying to approximately solve this mathematically for D.  That is,  to figure out out what are the chances of getting a D win in the first  6 cards is, then multiplying that by 47 to account for a win in any deck position after that, pretty much randomly distributed I would think..

Comment: I already checked your data and reported the result when I mentioned that after fixing the problem with cases like 2223344 I got your results. - Of course it is randomly distributed, but not uniform. There had to be a slight bias to lower numbers, but the peak at 6 surprised me. I guess it's not clearly visible with stats from your ~1.6*10^5 D wins, but after 10^6 wins it begins to show. Simply using 47 as multiplier was a bold decision that worked amazingly well, but not good enough since the odds for C and D are so close.

Comment: How can winning hands be rare? There are about 3/1000 chance of winning, so multiply with 10^50 we get a gigantic number.

Comment: Also this still depends on stimulation. How can you be sure this it's better than plain simulation?

Comment: @user202729 Oh, the wonders of multiplication! Now I see how to win at lotto! :-)

Comment: @user202729 While I nowhere claimed that it is better, I think it obviously is because I can handle more winning hands in the same time. The results that don't depend on the "leverage trick" are especially trustworthy. So I am sure that I have the better estimate for the ratio of real to candidate ties. You also need a lot of results for the first graph. (This is a case where the C player variant is less demanding.)

Answer (score 3):

My simulation program works by first shuffling the entire $52$ card deck and then searching the entire deck for candidate wins for each player, then simply selecting the candidate win with the lowest drawn card position.  Normally there is only $1$ candidate win per winning hand as can be seen by only $769$ candidate ties.  A candidate tie is when the program detects a possible win for both players, which are normally at different final drawn card positions, but very rarely will be the same.  In $22$ cases they were the same, thus resulting in a tie.  It was easier for me to let the program search the entire $52$ card deck then to just draw $1$ card at a time looking for winners after each card (after the $6$th card is drawn which is the minimum # of cards needed for a player D win).

I have some results from a simulation program. Also it is interesting that since the game is so close to $50/50$, as the simulation runs, the partial results show C sometimes winning.  This is why $1$ million hands is not enough.

$1,000,000,000$ : simulated hands.
$24$ hours : approx runtime using interpreted language.
$11,500$ : approx # of hands played per second.
$3.06$ Ghz dual core Intel : CPU speed but only $50$% used by simulation.
$152,981$ : wins for player C.
$157,822$ : wins for player D.
$49.22$% : $50.78$% ... approx ratio of C wins to D wins.
$99.9689$% : approx percentage of nonwinning hands (deck exhausted without a winner).
$41.1453$ : approx # of average cards drawn for C win (only counting when C actually wins).
$28.9136$ : approx # of average cards drawn for D win (only counting when D actually wins).
$769$ : candidate ties (both players have possible win in entire shuffled deck).
$22$ : actual ties.
$35:1$ approx candidate tie to actual tie ratio.
$6537$ : approx average hands per C win.
$6336$ : approx average hands per D win.
$3217$ : approx average hands for any win (or tie).
$45,454,545$ : approx average hands for a tie.

I am hoping someone else can do some analysis too to help confirm these numbers.  Perhaps some mathematical calculations to help show that player D has a slight advantage.  Also if someone would like some other stats tracked in the simulation program just let me know in the comment section and I can try to put it in and then post those results.

Here are the patterns we need to check for a possible C win.  Note each length $3$ straight can appear in any order so for example, $234678TJQ$ and $678234TJQ$ are equally good winners for player C.  Those are just $2$ of the $6$ possible permutations of each of these $10$ main patterns.  So there are $ 60$ actual patterns including permutations.  The comma indicates any number of cards (including $0$ cards) may appear as long as the pattern continues.  For example, in  pattern $1$, if the drawn cards are $K234J7ATJQ2495678$, that is a winner for player C cuz it follows (a permutation of) a winning pattern.

$~~1)~234,678,TJQ$
$~~2)~234,678,JQK$
$~~3)~234,678,QKA$
$~~4)~234,789,JQK$
$~~5)~234,789,QKA$
$~~6)~234,89T,QKA$
$~~7)~345,789,JQK$
$~~8)~345,789,QKA$
$~~9)~345,89T,QKA$
$10)~456,89T,QKA$

The winning patterns for D are (no permutations are allowed):

$~~1)~234567$
$~~2)~345678$
$~~3)~456789$
$~~4)~56789T$
$~~5)~6789TJ$
$~~6)~789TJQ$
$~~7)~89TJQK$
$~~8)~9TJQKA$
$~~9)~223344$
$10)~334455$
$11)~445566$
$12)~556677$
$13)~667788$
$14)~778899$
$15)~8899TT$
$16)~99TTJJ$
$17)~TTJJQQ$
$18)~JJQQKK$
$19)~QQKKAA$

Note that for player D, NO permutations of these $19$ patterns are allowed.  They must appear EXACTLY as shown here.  For example, $QQJJKK$ is NOT a win for player D.  This is a clarification not a rule change.

It is somewhat amazing to me that wins are rare for both C and D (based on the average number of hands between wins), but they are almost equally as rare, making it almost $50/50~$ like a fair coin toss.

In case anyone is interested, I had the program display the cards for all $22$ ties.  It displays the entire deck in the shuffled order for that hand so you can just trace where the tie occurred. For example, in the first tie, the relevant cards are $,345,89T,9TJQKA$.  Here is a cropped partial screenshot for the simulation output for the ties: (T= ten).

[image]

I will now attempt to solve this mathematically but in a very simple way.

Looking at player's D's ways to win, there are only $2$ patterns.  Pattern $1$ which is a $6$ card straight has probability $32/52 * 4/51 * 4/50 * 4/49 * 4/48 * 4/47$ but this is the probability of getting the $6$ card straight on the first $6$ cards drawn so we multiply that by $47$, assuming the straight can appear equally likely anywhere in the deck.  So far that is about $1 / 9518$.

Next we have player D's 2nd pattern such as ($223344,334455, ... ,QQKKAA$) so that is $44/52 * 3/51 * 4/50 * 3/49 * 4/48 * 3/47$ but again we have to multiply that by $47$ since that $6$ card pattern can appear anywhere in the deck so we get $1/16407$.  Adding the 2 probabilities we get $1/6024$ which is fairly close to the probability reported by the simulation program which was $1/6336$.  The slight difference could be a combination of interaction with C's wins, ties, and the patterns not being uniformly distributed in all $47$ positions, but considering the simplicity of the calculations, it is quite a good approximation, only roughly $5$% off.  For example, imagine we get $234567$ very late in the deck.  It is quite possible that $234$, $345$, or $456$ can give C the win instead, or $567$ can give C and D a tie.  Thus we would expect D's win chances to be lower than $1/6024$ which means the denominator has to be larger, more like $1/6336$.  Also we must consider cases where multiple $6$ card straights appear.  For example, it maybe possible that $234567$ appears early in the deck but something like $6789TJ$ appears much later (towards the end of the deck). Using my simple math, I would overcount these.  I think worst case there could be $8$ straights of length $6$ in the same deck but that would be an astronomically rare event.  Perhaps something like $234567,~234567,~234567,~234567,~89TJQK,~89TJQK,~89TJQK,~9TJQKA$.  In my simulation program, I could count up how many times  a straight of length $6$ appears multiple times in the same shuffled deck and add that to the table of results.

So I have done some of the work for you.  I just need someone to somehow compute the interactions and account for those in the final probability.  I will attempt to calculate C's win probability, also using simple math if possible.

Now let's look at C's win pattern.  Let's take $234,678,TJQ$ as an example.  Any one of those $3$ card patterns can appear first.  Let's suppose the $234$ appeared first.  The first part of this pattern MUST appear by card draw $46$ to allow ample time for the other part of the pattern to appear.  To get $234$ on the first $3$ card draw we have probability $4/52 * 4/51 * 4/50$ = $1/2072$.  From here it gets more complicated.  Placing the three $3$ card straights might be one of those stars and bars type problems.  Just find the probability of getting the $234,678,TJQ$ in order (without completing a $6$ card straight) and then multiply by $6$ to account for the possible permutations of them.  Then multiply by $10$ to account for the $9$ other similar win patterns for C.  This should be a rough approximation.  Treat the $234$ as one entity and just place it anywhere in the $52$ card deck and do the same for the $678$ and $TJQ$.  That is stars and bars.  I think one way to solve this is to use stars and bars with a gap space of at least $2$ (such as $2,3,4,i,j,6,7,8$ so we are guaranteed not to have a $6$ card straight, then handle the cases where the gap space is $1$ separately so that we can make sure we only place cards there that will not complete the $6$ card straight.  Also if anyone needs a certain count of some pattern that will help them to use math to solve this just let me know and I can try to create a bucket for it in my sim prog.  I would love to get an exact answer to this problem but based on the lack and answers here (even with a $150$ bounty), I am assuming it is not easy.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you  mean by equi-probable cards.  You mean having a deck where the drawn cards are replaced?   As far as treating each pattern (rule) separately, I see your point.  For example, for D, $334455$ and $445566$ are related in that they both share $4455$.  So imagine if $33445566$ appears in the shuffled deck.  That is a win based on $334455$ but not on the $445566$, which, if cards were drawn $1$ at a time, we would never get to.  Because I shuffle the deck each time, I can "see" all the cards and will see patterns like $33445566$.  Good point.

Comment: @igael, okay thanks and yes I agree it is interesting in that there is no way to "cheat" to get the correct answer.  A computer can give a good approximation.  Also, as you get more reputation points you get more privileges.  Good luck I hope you can solve it.  A good solution will show for certain who has the advantage and will explain why.  I simulated 1 billion hands but that doesn't prove D has an advantage for certain.  What if I did 1 trillion hands might it reverse to C favored?  I doubt it but it is possible, so technically I did not prove D has the advantage for certain.

Comment: Another interesting example would be something like $K234J67826789TJQ$. Here we have the first good $3$ card straight at cards $234$, the 2nd at $678$, but then we get the $6$ card straight before we get the 3rd gapped $3$ card straight. So the winning card sequence is $6789TJ$ for player D. Player C needed TJQ for the 3rd gapped $3$ card straight but player D already won $1$ card previous to that.

Comment: An example that illustrates a C win more clearly would be $234234234234678TJQ$  Here only the first $234$ is relevant to the win cuz the other ones are not gapped.  $678$ IS gapped and so is $TJQ$ so when we get the Q card it is a win for player C.  My sim prog will simply search that string for the first occurrence of $234$ (which ends at card position $3$), then it will immediately search for the next good $3$ card straight which is $678$ and then to do the same for $TJQ$ and then it will report a win for C. Very simple algorithm only searching for $3$ card straights that are good for a win.

Comment: The difference between your estimate and observed number of D wins can not be explained by C wins. These cases would appear as candidate ties in your simulation, and these are much rarer than the 5% difference. The difference (which unfortunately is big compared to the difference of chances of C and D) comes nearly completely from the simplifications in the estimate.

Comment: @Christian Sievers - okay I will "buy" that explanation. One related subquestion that is significant here is are D wins (length $6$ straight) uniformly distributed for all ending card draws from $6$ to $52$? If not, then we cannot just take the probability of a $6$ card straight appearing in the first $6$ cards and then simply multiply it by $47$ which is the number of positions a length $6$ straight can appear in a $52$ card deck. However, it is impressive that the very simple math comes suspiciously close to the simulation results (which I assume are accurate but someone will check).

Comment: You have the same probability for straight cards from 1..6 as from i..i+5, but in the letter case you could also have had other 6 straight cards before that position, so you are overcounting these cases. If ending cards 6..52 were uniformly distributed, we would have that in the average winning case, D needed 29 cards, which I find is still surprisingly close to the value you observed.

Comment: $(6+52)/2$ = $29$ so it appears the $6$ card straights ARE appearing  somewhat uniformly distributed, otherwise there would be a bias away from the middle position of $29$ here.  We do not include final card positions $1..5$ since a $6$ card straight is not possible there.  I ran a quick simulation of $5$ million hands and made the program show the distribution of final cards for D wins and it looks fairly uniform.  The program reported $826$ D wins.  Count range for ending cards is $11$ low and $26$ high which seems right since $17.57$ is average.  A few buckets are $17$ or $18$.

Comment: I think cuz the $6$ card straights are fairly rare (about $1$ out of $6000$+) it can be said that they are expected to be uniformly distributed over ending card positions $6..52$.  One way of explaining this is the "crap" cards that contribute nothing to the straight and actually mess it up can also appear "randomly", thus allowing the straight to form anywhere as equally likely.  For example, you might think it is more rare for a $6$ card straight to form at the very end of the deck but from the previous comment simulation, it showed a bucket value of $21$ so it happens as expected.

Comment: If I got those statistics (that I just had to read about) right, then the standard deviation of the mean of $N$ values from a uniform distribution of 6..52 is $\sqrt{184/N}$, so with $N=10^9$ we have that 28.87 is more than 300 standard deviations away from the mean 29. So we do see a strong bias away from 29, which I think is not surprising for the reasons given before.

Comment: Oh no, I may only count those experiments where D wins, so it's only $N=157730$, so we are only 3.8 standard deviations away from 29. That's much less drastic, but still a lot. (And keep in mind that that is not the standard deviation of your results which I don't know, but the one we would have if it were a uniform distribution. I expect them to be approximately the same.)

Comment: What happened to @igael?  All of that persons comments appear to have been deleted.  This person was so convinced that their code was right and that I was changing my rules but neither of those were true.  Although if this person got $470$ wins for player C using my test data that is a good sign.

Comment: I don't know about his reasons and thoughts, but by making the same mistake (and surprisingly getting exactly his results, and by comparing @user202729's results with mine) I noticed that we missed D's win in cases like 2223344. After fixing that, I get your results. - And before you ask, I'm not interested in downloading an even bigger file. If you want, write a portable program using a deterministic random number generator to generate test data.

Comment: @Christian Sievers - I can see that mistake happening if you check for wins after each card is drawn, which is why instead I scan the entire $52$ card shuffled deck for candidate wins, then simply choose the one with the lower finishing card position (in the rare cases that C and D both have candidate wins in the same shuffled deck).  I simple search for $223344$ and my program will easily find it. I only made 1 very minor mistake programming this and once fixed, seems "on the money".  However, if the problem was instead to find ties such that D had 2 or more candidate wins, would be too slow.

Comment: Continuation from previous comment:  That is, the reason we can simulate this and get reasonably accurate percentages for C and D wins is cuz they each happen roughly every $6000$ hands or so.  If some event we were checking for happened MUCH less frequently, then simulation would not be a very good option.  For example, if some event was $1$ in $1$ quintillion ($1$ / $10^{18}$), then Monte Carlo style simulation would not help much.

Comment: @igael I'm not sure I understand you correctly. I couldn't tell you about finding the problem with 2223344 because your answer was already deleted, so I only mentioned it here. (For a fun result, try the simulation with your old shuffling algorithm, but re-initialize the array to 22223333...AAAA each time before shuffling. Then do the same, but re-initialize to 23456789TJQK234... ) Not sure what you mean with scripts and links.

Comment: @igael How many weeks is a few weeks?

Comment: @user202729: I remove my answers where they needed a lot of work and were not appreciated. ( I did it again 10 min ago ). Today, I don't remember this subject. At the time when I wrote this comment, I was not aware of the duplicate system. Sorry. I will remove my remaining remarks which are no more relevant after you read this message...

Answer (score 2):

I also simulate a version, using C++ `mt19937` generator and Fisher–Yates shuffle (perhaps that is why this is slow).
Result:

```
nowin: 19993847, cwin: 2993, dwin: 3160, tie: 0
```

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
std::mt19937 mt(123456789); // mersenne twister generator using a seed

enum card {c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, cT, cJ, cQ, cK, cA};

enum type {straight, alternate};

card deck [52] {
    c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, cT, cJ, cQ, cK, cA,
    c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, cT, cJ, cQ, cK, cA,
    c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, cT, cJ, cQ, cK, cA,
    c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, cT, cJ, cQ, cK, cA,
};

void shuffle() {
    card temp; int pos;
    for (int i = 52; i > 1;) {
        pos = mt() % i; // generate random int in [0, i)
        i--;
        temp = deck[i];
        deck[i] = deck[pos];
        deck[pos] = temp;
    }
}

short prevtrans[256][13]; /* prevtrans[prev][card] = newprev.
prev: (total 8 bit)
    first bit: 0 is straight, 1 is alternate - type.
    4 next bit: from 0 to 12, indicate *FIRST* card - p1card.
    3 last bit: from 0 to 5, indicate length minus 1 - len1. (if length = 6 then D win instantly)
    There are a lot of redundancies.
*/
bool cwinp[2048]; /* cwinp[cwinpart] is true if cwinpart gives an instant win for C.
    cwinpart consists of 11 bits <QKA, JQK, ..., 456, 345, 234>.
    There are a lot of redundancies. For example, 567 and 9TJ are always 0.
*/
short cwinbuild[256]; /* The value to be ORed to cwin given prev to build a better cwin. */

void init() { // init those three tables.
    for (int prev = 0; prev < 256; prev++) {
        int type = prev >> 7, p1card = (prev >> 3) & 15, len1 = prev & 7; // bit extract
        int pcard = p1card + (type == alternate ? len1 >> 1 : len1);
        for (int ncard = 0; ncard < 13; ncard++) {
            if (pcard >= 13 || len1 >= 6) continue; // as I said, there are a lot of redundancies
            if (pcard == ncard) {
                if (type == alternate && (len1 & 1) == 0)
                    prevtrans[prev][ncard] = (prev & 0b11111000) | (len1 + 1); // build next alternate
                else // either bad alternate or straight
                    prevtrans[prev][ncard] = (alternate << 7) | (ncard << 3) | 1; // reset to alternate, length = 2 -> len1 = 1
            } else if (pcard + 1 == ncard) { // straight at least 2
                if (type == alternate) {
                    if ((len1 & 1) == 1) // good alternate
                        prevtrans[prev][ncard] = (prev & 0b11111000) | (len1 + 1); // build next alternate
                    else if (len1 != 0) // (likely) bad alternate, form straight 3 (len1 = 2)
                        prevtrans[prev][ncard] = (straight << 7) | ((pcard - 1) << 3) | 2;
                    else // (unlikely) short alternate, form straight 2 (len1 = 1)
                        prevtrans[prev][ncard] = (straight << 7) | (pcard << 3) | 1;
                }
                else /*if (type == straight)*/ {
                    prevtrans[prev][ncard] = (prev & 0b11111000) | (len1 + 1); // build next straight
                }
            } else { // ncard do not form a pattern with pcard, straight 1 (len1 == 0)
                prevtrans[prev][ncard] = /*(straight << 7) | */(ncard << 3)/* | 0*/;
            }
            //std::cout << "prevtrans[" << prbin(prev, 8) << "][" << ncard << "] = " << prbin(prevtrans[prev][ncard], 8) << "\n";
        }
        cwinbuild[prev] = (type == straight && len1 >= 2 ? // so length >= 3
        1 << (p1card + len1 - 2) : 0);
    }
    for (short cwinpart = 0; cwinpart < 2048; cwinpart++) {
        const short cwindone[10] = {
            0b00100010001, // 234, 678, TJQ
            0b01000010001, // 234, 678, JQK
            0b10000010001, // 234, 678, QKA
            0b01000100001, // 234, 789, JQK
            0b10000100001, // 234, 789, QKA
            0b10001000001, // 234, 89T, QKA
            0b01000100010, // 345, 789, JQK
            0b10000100010, // 345, 789, QKA
            0b10001000010, // 345, 89T, QKA
            0b10001000100, // 456, 89T, QKA
        };
        cwinp[cwinpart] = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            if ( // cwinpart is a superset of cwindone[i]
                (cwindone[i] &~ cwinpart) == 0) {
                    cwinp[cwinpart] = true;
                    break;
                }
    }
}

int main() {
    init();
    short prev, cwinpart;
    int cwin = 0, dwin = 0, tie = 0, nowin = 0, i;
    for (int cnt = 0; cnt < 20000000; cnt++) { // 100 millions. Consider switch to long long if necessary
        shuffle();
        prev = 0b01100000; // straight A length=1. Cannot benefit for C or D.
        cwinpart = 0b00000000000; // not got anything for C.
        for (i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
            prev = prevtrans[prev][deck[i]];
            cwinpart |= cwinbuild[prev];    
            if ((prev & 7) == 5) {// len1 == 5 <=> length = 6. D win instantly.
                if (cwinp[cwinpart])
                    tie++;
                else
                    dwin++;
                break;
            } else if (cwinp[cwinpart]) {
                cwin++;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (i == 52)
            nowin++;
    }
    std::cout << "nowin: " << nowin << ", cwin: " << cwin << ", dwin: " << dwin << ", tie: " << tie;
    std::string s;
    std::cin >> s;
}
```

I have an idea to completely solve the problem with computer-assisted (perhaps in a few days), but the memory take is several TBs. The basic idea is, given a deck (not count permutation, so there is 5^13 decks, or "submultiset" of the original deck), previous some cards (count permutation) (`prev` in my code), and partial winning data for C (`cwinpart` in my code), you can calculate the probability by the probability of other decks with less card, so you can use Dynamic Programming can be useful here.

**Edit:** To solve the problem exactly you can use the following code:

```
void calcp(long long board, // board: 3 bits for each number, AKQJT98765432 -> 39 bits
    short prev, short cwinpart, double& cwin, double& dwin, double& tie
) {
    // < Check for base cases: board == 0LL >
    cwin = dwin = tie = 0.;
    int ncard = 0, sumcard = 0;
    short nprev;
    double cwin1, dwin1, tie1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
        ncard = (board >> (3 * i)) & 07;
        if (ncard != 0) {
            sumcard += ncard;
            nprev = prevtrans[prev][i];
            calcp(board - (1 << (3 * i)), nprev, cwinpart | cwinbuild[nprev],
                    cwin1, dwin1, tie1);
            cwin += cwin1 * ncard;
            dwin += dwin1 * ncard;
            tie += tie1 * ncard;
        }
    }
    cwin /= sumcard;
    dwin /= sumcard;
    tie /= sumcard;
}

int main() {
    init();
    double cwin = 0., dwin = 0., tie = 0.; // probability
    calcp(04444444444444LL, 0b01100000, 0b00000000000, cwin, dwin, tie);
    std::cout << cwin << " " << dwin << " " << tie << "\n";
}
```

There are some notes:

1. The code use tables, enums, functions from the previous my code part.
2. You should add memoization to the function (wisely, because there are about $2\times 10^{13}$ different inputs) to decrease the time.
   The code is easy to understand providing you know C++11.

**Edit:** Result from your test:
`count: 3000000 nowin: 2999046, cwin: 470, dwin: 484, tie: 0`

I have made a fault in my code (see revision). Now our result accept.

Comment: I have my sample data of $3$ million random shuffles here.  Try running your program on my sample data and we can compare results and figure out where the discrepancy (if any) is occuring.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BweDAVsuCEM1amhsNmFITnEwd2s/view?usp=sharing.  Format is one $52$ byte shuffle per line with $2$ bytes for end of line so $54$ bytes per line total.  $3$ million records/shuffles/lines.  File is zipped  so you will have to unzip (extract) the raw data which should be $162,000,000$ bytes

Comment: It's 22:23 at my position and I can't use a computer now. Why don't you try it yourself?

Comment: I don't have a compiler that will handle your code @user202729

Comment: I use Code Blocks.

Comment: Also you need to run more trials like 1 billion to get it to stabilize, otherwise you could get a "swing" away from the expected values.  I've seen that many times with a "low" number of trials.  Below 1 million and C can actually be wrongly reported as the overall expected winner.  This is cuz the expected probabilities are so close to 50/50 that a short set of trials can go either way.

Comment: Only way to know for (almost) certain if our $3$ simulation programs are equivalent or different is to run them on a fixed set of data and compare results.  Ideally the data should be 1 billion records but it is not really practical yet for me to upload such a huge file.  Read in the datafile and bypass the shuffle and the program may run even quicker.  Mine ran about 7 times as quick using the preshuffled data but it is an interpreted language not compiled so I would suspect in a compiled language the speed difference would be less. - @user202729.

Comment: How do you get 5^13 decks?

Comment: @ChristianSievers Not count permutation.

Comment: @user202729 - Wow you got $490$ C wins and $558$ D wins from my data file?  I got $470$ C wins and $484$ D wins (C=$49.27$% , D=$50.73$%).  Our results are WAY different.

Comment: So you're thinking of the submultisets of $\{2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,\dots,A,A,A,A\}$ that appear as possibilities for the remaining cards to be dealt. That's clever!

Comment: @David 1. I edited my answer. 2. Use a generator and a engine is better. That's why I seeded 123456789 and generator mt19937. You should read my code and learn C++11.

Comment: @user202729 - Ok very good  we are getting the same exact results!  Since we have another week to play with this very interesting problem I made up from scratch, I think we should really do a "stress test".  I can have my program generate 1 billion shuffles and output them in the same format as the 3 million shuffle data file.  I will NOT tell you my # of winners and ties ahead of time but rather wait for your results.  If they match then we are almost guaranteed our programs are equivalent and both correct.  The zipped file will be about 26GB so can you download that much in reasonable time?

Comment: @user202729 - Well to be sure we should use the same exact data. How about a reasonable compromise of $1.9$ GB zip file? That will help keep things manageable and stay under the 4GB limit of some file systems for the raw (unzipped) data. That will be close to $75$ million shuffles. Also what I can do is manually insert a few by hand which are "special cases" to see if our programs both handle those properly.  Cases like $23467889T234567$ (should be a win for D).  The other test method you mentioned sounds like a   good candidate but I would need more details first please on how to do it..

Comment: Remember that `this is not a programming site`. But you don't want to learn C++, and still want to check in that way, then download http://www.mediafire.com/download/yu2o8951854by7n/fcardgame.exe , put your file to `C:\input.txt`, then run the program. You should try with small input first to see how the program output.

Comment: @user202729 - Yes I tried downloading it but it didn't run cuz it told me it is missing a .DLL.  I am still running Windows XP.  It tells me this application has failed to start because libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll was not found.

Comment: @user202729 Try adding "-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++" linker switches then repost the new exe so I can try to download it or just include the DLL for people to also download.

Comment: @user202729 - Actually my idea seems to work better which is to just share a datafile and then anyone can just run it thru their program.  That way we don't have to deal with missing DLLs, different Operating Systems...  All those different environments should work just by reading in a copy of the same datafile.  That is the simplest way.  I can just keep the datafile size reasonable like $1$ GB or smaller.

Comment: @David I think you are the only person who need that exe. New version: http://www.mediafire.com/download/wluy9f33ud3vlpk/fscanf_cardgame.exe . If you make huge input, then I won't run it.

Comment: @David Do you know the cube20 problem and the 4-coloring theorem? They are all solved by supercomputer. And this problem is also quite hard, similar to them. Given several TB of memory I can solve it.

Comment: @user202729 - Same missing DLL error for that new EXE.  If you make it so it links in that DLL using those static linker flags, it might work for me. I think I have heard of those problems but don't know them well.  What is amazing to me about this problem is using super simple math, I got a very good approximation to D's win probability like within about $5$% of the real probability. If you prune the state space of this to only those situation where a win is possible, how many states would the computer have to generate and scan?  Seems using a combination of math and computers it is solvable.

Comment: I added those flags, but it failed. You can try downloading the DLL and put it to windows\system32 folder. Also have you understood the exact part of my code? Seems not so you said "pruning". If so I have to explain it to you @David . You can separate the data file into 4 part: no one win, C win, D win, tie to minimize the error. It is possible that a program swap the result of two decks and still return correct result. (Total 3 questions from me)

Comment: @user202729 - There should be way for you to create a standalone EXE (executable) such that someone else doesn't need a similar runtime environment as you.  I looked up this problem online and there are multiple possible solutions.  I'd like to be able to run your program on my same computer that I run mine for both speed comparison and result comparison cuz I have very large test files here.  The only other solution is I can have my large testfile uploaded and you run it there and share your results with me.  I wont tell you how many C and D wins at first but will after for comparison.

Comment: @David **Read my comments carefully.** 1. I said that I have total 3 questions, and you haven't replied yet. 2. I will **NOT** download larger test files. 3. You can find that dll at https://download.dll-files.com/c81c2063954800835adc179294cea84f/libgcc_s_dw2-1.zip?0XJdT0aGiR if you can't find that yourself. The comments are getting long so I don't want to repeat `have you understood the exact part of my code?` many more times.

Comment: @David So you'd like to be able to run ..., so why don't you run it? Just download the dll and put it into `\Windows\System32`. Have you tried that?

Comment: @David If D were the only player, then there would be 47 positions $((1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), ..., (47, 48,49,50,51,52))$ that he can win. At each position there are $19$ patterns so there are $47\times 19 = 893$ events. Since the events are (nearly) independent (even if they are heavily dependent, it will still be a lot of calculation), then to calculate exactly we need $2^{893}$ calculations.Without calculating all then it might be less, but then combining with C's winning events,it gets enormous quickly.Also please answer `have you understood the exact part of my code?` soon.

Comment: @user202729 - No I cannot get your program to run.  I put 2 DLLs it was asking for in my C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32 folder but I am still getting some error that it cannot run so it is very frustrating which is why I greatly prefer sharing datafiles and letting people manage their own programs and then just sharing results.  It would be  fairly easy for me to post a large file (perhaps $30$ million records instead of just $3$ million).  That file zipped would still be under 1GB so should download in reasonable time.  No I don't understand your code well I am old school I just use simple programming.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44210/discussion-between-user202729-and-david).

Answer (score 0):

This is a 2nd answer for those of you that are considering using computer simulation or a combination of that and math.  If you use a computer language that has good string functions like I did, a simple algorithm is to put the patterns "$234$", "$345$", "$456$"... "$QKA$" in an array.  I indexed them from $2$ to $12$ to keep is simple cuz the index matches the lowest ranked card in the $3$ card straight.  Then just run $3$ nested loops, call them i, j and k. The outermost loop index i goes from $2$ to $4$ since one of those patterns MUST appear for a C win.  That is, either $234$, $345$, or $456$ MUST appear for C to win.  The middle loop (j) iterates from (i+$4$) to $8$. Notice this middle loop never goes higher than $8$ cuz we need room for the gap and then the final $3$ card straight.  The innermost loop (k) iterates from (j+$4$) to $12$.  If a $3$ card straight is found from each of the $3$ groups (thus indicating they are all gapped by at least $1$ rank), then that is a win for player C unless a $6$ card straight is also found in the deck, in which case I just compare final card positions of both to determine who really won the hand.  Most of the time this is not necessary cuz there is only $1$ candidate winner which is the actual winner.

D wins are also put in an array and the entire shuffled deck is scanned for them.  Examples would be DW[$1$] = "$234567$"  DW[$2$] = "$345678$"....  Of course since multiple D winning patterns may appear in the same shuffled deck, I ultimately choose the one with the lowest finishing card position.  For example, $345678A234567$ is a "double" candidate win for D but the winning sequence is $345678$ and NOT $234567$ although my simulation is programmed to search for $234567$ first.

So to be clear, using strings is a very good way to simulate this card game cuz many languages have good fast string searching functions built in and it makes the coding much simpler in my opinion as an "old school" programmer.

Just to be clear, my sim prog shuffles and scans the entire deck but when a candidate win is found, if it is a solo candidate win (such as player C only), then the win is awarded and the card position is recorded for averaging later.  An interesting scenario happens when there are $2$ candidate wins in the same $52$ card deck.  A very simple example would be $234678TJQ234567...$ Here, my program will detect possible (candidate) wins for both C and D but will see that the C win happened first and award the win only to C.  Reason I scan the entire deck is cuz it is simpler and it also allows me to track additional interesting info like dual candidate winners in the same hand which is rare, and of those few, some ties appear which are even more rare.

Someone asked about my shuffle routine so I will describe it here.  I start with the deck initialized to rank order.  The array (call it A here) is such that A[$1$] = '$2$', A[$2$] = '$2$', A[$3$] =  '$2$', A[$4$] = '$2$', A[$5$] = $3$... A[$52$] = 'A'.

The goal is to choose a random card from the deck and place it at the "tail end" of the deck.  This is a variation of the Fisher-Yates shuffle. So 1st iteration of shuffle will grab a random number from $1$ to $52$ (inclusive).  That number will be the position of the card in array A we want to place at the "end" of the deck.  So for example, if the random number is $5$, we already know that A[$5$] = '$3$' (a rank 3 card is there) so we do the swap.  Next we only concentrate on the first $51$ cards in the deck so we grab a random number from $1$ to $51$ and do another swap, but this time with the 2nd to last card in the deck which is our new "tail end" of the deck.  This process continues until the deck size we are concentrating on is only size $1$.  In that case we can just exit the shuffle cuz now all $52$ cards will have had an equal opportunity to be in any of the $52$ card positions.  The Rand() function I call is a library function  so I have little control over it but I have been using it in many card and dice simulation programs and it has agreed with others results so it seems very reliable, accurate, and fast.  I am not sure how it works internally but it seems to work very well, showing no bias.

Comment: Your description doesn't explain that one can't stop after finding the first triple $(i,j,k)$. Test case: do you recognize 234678JQK234567TJQ as win for C? You might not if you stopped after finding TJQ as third run of 3 straight cards and ignored the earlier run JQK of higher ranked cards. (Such a thing could also happen with the first or second run.)

Comment: @Christian Sievers - you are exactly right!  I typed in your example deal and it incorrectly reported a win for D.  However, since this case is extremely rare, it wont upset the numbers significantly.  That is cuz this is a candidate tie condition and those are very rare.  Even if I corrected the code, the percentage would not change significantly but you are exactly right this is a flaw in my nested loop logic.  It is telling me a candidate tie but with C win position at card $18$ and D win card position at $15$ so  it gives D the win but C actually should have won at card position $9$.

Comment: I will fix my code even though it is not a critical error.  D will still be the winner overall by about a $51$% to $49$% favorite over C.  Still a very good catch and it shows a good understanding of the rules, even better than myself that made up this question.  I will attempt to fix my code now.  By the way, it only takes $2$ lines of code to change to test your example.  To fix the code is not so straightforward since there could  be many $3$ card straights with an embedded $6$ card straight so the easy solution would be to perhaps change the code to check after each card draw.  Thinking...

Comment: I agree that it will not change the winning percentages much. I guess it will have a bigger influence to the average number of cards drawn before C wins (here not only candidate ties are affected).

Comment: I guess you jumped out of the inner loop? Can't you just take the highest used index (as before), compare with a possible earlier result, and continue the loop? Then there is no difference if C doesn't have a "candidate win".

Comment: Yes as soon as I find the 3rd component of a candidate C win I bust out of all 3 loops by setting the LCV (loop control variable(s)) to a high number.  Not a good programming method but works.  I suppose I could let the loops iterate over all $10$ patterns, put them in an array with card positions, then just choose the $3$ with the lowest card positions.  In fact if I make the array size $52$ for all possible card positions the  $3$ card straights can end at and initialize the array to $0$, I can then just go thru the array and pluck off the $3$ lowest nonzero card positions. Good idea thanks!

Comment: BTW, there is potentially a similar problem with D's winning patterns. Given 3456789JQK234567, one better not stops after finding 234567 as D's winning pattern.

Comment: Yes I already had that in place.  That is I looked for the lowest possible card position already for D but I didn't also have that check for C until you pointed it out.  You are very good at catching anomalous cases thanks.  I reran the corrected program on the $10$ million pre-shuffled hands stored in a file and the interpreted program only took about $2$ minutes to run and give me the results (less time than shuffle). C and D are indeed "neck and neck" but I still see D as a very slight favorite. I don't yet want to give away the exact numbers in case someone else wants to test on same data.